# Is input arguments to a function returned always by default?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return, return-value

I have a function like given below. The code works fine and I require your assistance only in helping me to understand how the `return` or function output is stored. I am a beginner and your inputs would be helpful

```
dataFramesDict = dict()

def create_df(xls,s): 
   ......
   return sheet_df,sheet_name

def transform_stage_1_df(sheet_df,sheet_name):
    ..... 
    .....
    return sheet_df,sheet_name

def transform_stage_2_df(sheet_df, sheet_name):

     result = pd.concat(....)
     return result
```

As you can see, I am only returning the `result` dataframe as output from the function. No other variables are returned from function

When I call the function in sequence like below, **I expect it throw an error** at the last line for `dataFramesDict[sheet_name]` but it works fine.

```
sheet_df,sheet_name = create_df(xls,s)
sheet_df,sheet_name = transform_stage_1_df(sheet_df,sheet_name)
dataFramesDict[sheet_name] = transform_stage_2_df(sheet_df,sheet_name)
```

Shouldn't I be getting an error message like below

> sheet_name isn't defined

I tried restarting the kernel to make sure that it's not defined elsewhere.

Because `sheet_name` isn't a global variable. It is only passed as an argument to the above function. Does function always return input arguments by default as well?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Obviously you already have a variable named `sheet_name` since you can call the function passing it as an argument. Why do you expect the interpreter to raise an error? Also what do you mean by _restarting the kernel_?

Comment: @Selcuk - As shown in updated post, Sheet_name is passed as an argument because it is returned as an output from another function. So shouldn't the scope be valid only within that function

Comment: You are declaring `sheet_name` in your first line, using the second value of the tuple returned by `create_df`. What is not clear to you?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand now. I was thinking only about the arguments and not about output variables used to store the function output. Might be I should rename them and avoid duplicates

Comment: All the below answers helped me to figure out what's the mistake I did and understand the scope of variables. Thanks for your response. I am marking @Devandra Swami answer as solution as it got has more upvotes when compared to other answer.  Anyway I have upvoted both the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable sheet_name is defined outside transform_stage_2_df as you are using it as an input parameter and thus is already defined outside.

```
dataFramesDict[sheet_name] = transform_stage_2_df(sheet_df,sheet_name)
```

Comment: But I didn't define it as a gobal variable. It's all within the function. Am I doing anything incorrect?  upvoted.

Comment: you can see in your code itself that sheet_name is already defined outside your function transform_stage_2_df and assigned as one of the output parameter of your create_df function.

Comment: It might be because of your code style that sheet_name inside your function transform_stage_2_df and outside evaluate to same value. But they are referring to different memory. You can use id(sheet_name) and print inside fn and outside and they will output different values.

Comment: Okay, so the variables that we used to store output of a function can be used anywhere. Am I following a bad practice by naming them all identical?

Comment: It is fine as long as you have basic understanding of scope of variables. You have assigned output in the caller namespace.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198277/discussion-between-ssmk-and-devendra-swami).

Answer (score 2):

sheet_df,sheet_name, and unit_dict were not defined in the scope of the line in the initial question. In your edits to the question, you showed where all of those variables are being set. Since they are being set in prior lines, there is no mystery.

return does not return the arguments or put them in scope.

Comment: I have updated the post. With few more info. Sheet_name is an return output from another function as shown above

Comment: @SSMK where is the line where you call create_df()?

Comment: Updated the post with few more lines

Comment: Yes, so on the line you added, sheet_name is defined. (It appears on the left side of the equals)